# How to use separate_rows in tidverse when the sep is ;

Tags: r, string, split, tidyr

I have a data frame whose one of the column has this data.
info1@domain.com; info2@domain.com; info3@domain.com

```
    q= tibble("info1@domain.com; info2@domain.com; info3@domain.com")
    separate_rows(q,sep = ";")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the column.
For your one and only column:

```
separate_rows(q,1 ,sep = ";") 

# A tibble: 3 × 1
  `"info1@domain.com; info2@domain.com; info3@domain.com"`
  <chr>                                                   
1 "info1@domain.com"                                      
2 " info2@domain.com"                                     
3 " info3@domain.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be clearer if you named the column. And you might want to use "; " (with a space) as the separator

```
q <- tibble(email = "info1@domain.com; info2@domain.com; info3@domain.com")
q %>% 
  separate_rows(email, sep = "; ")
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  email           
  <chr>           
1 info1@domain.com
2 info2@domain.com
3 info3@domain.com
```

Comment: does the "sep" accept REGEX?

Comment: @AJAY : I'm wondering if you looked at the help page? The default for sep is given as `sep = "[^[:alnum:].]+"`. That surely looks like a regex pattern to me.

Comment: Yes, i saw that. Thanks for all your help.